# RewriteRule adds .js not .php

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache2

I have this strange problem.
Here's my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^login/$ login.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ error.php [L]
```

The last rule works fine, giving me the /error.php page for any url it can't resolve. But if I go to mysite/login/, I get this 404 messagge:

```
The requested URL /login.js/ was not found on this server.
```

and this is odd because "login.js" isn't mentioned anywhere. I think it automatically adds ".js" to unknown urls or something. If I access mysite/login.php directly, I can see the correct .php page. I'm working on localhost, if this can help. Any suggestion?

Comment: If I access "mysite/login" it redirects me to "mysite/login.js", so I really think it automatically adds ".js", but I don't know where to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

If you want to remove .php extension from all the pages use above mentioned code.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but mhh, no. I want "mysite/login/" to redirect to "mysite/login.php", instead of "mysite/login.js/" as it misteriously does.

Comment: Means you need opposite rule. Are u using any cms or custom?